# Conflicts when merging into branch some changes in deleted code

Tags: svn, merge, branch

We've recently created a branch with a version of code customized for a certain client. We're working on both branches at the same time, commiting 'common' changes into the trunk, then merging them to the branch.

Recently, we've come to a troublesome situation. In `trunk/bar.c` we have (among others) a `foo()` function. Now, in `branch/bar.c` the function was removed, as there's no use for it there. The problems occur when `foo()` is modified in the `trunk`. When we merge the changes into the branch ("Merge range of revisions"), TortoiseSVN "3-way merge" tool shows **a conflict** on the method (that is annoying but I can see some reasons in that), but it does also show a whole **lot of other changes** in the file - which seem to appear out of thin air (looks a bit like if it wanted to show *all changes made between the trunk and the branch*). And that makes merging much more difficult, as it is littered with some unimportant and old changes.

Did situations like that occur to you? What would you suggest, especially to make spotting important differences easier during merge?

As a (hopefully) temporary resolution I'm going to try and `#ifdef` out the removed regions, so that SVN would think the code is still there and have better time with merging. (Unfortunately, that's going to make the code a bit ugly, and getting uglier when more functions are removed.)

Comment: I upvote because i have a similar problem

Comment: which version are you using (client and server)?  1.4?  1.5? ...

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider

1. whether your commits are frequent enough, and
2. whether you’re merging the correct revision or range of revisions.

It sounds to me like you aren’t getting quite the granularity that you want with your revisions; that is to say, one revision encompasses many changes.  Either that or you’re trying to merge a wider range of revisions than you need.  In any case, it may help if you commit more often.

For this particular case, you’ll have to merge the files manually — once you do, you should be able to merge subsequent revisions that don’t involve `foo()` without any intervention.

Comment: (1) yep; (2) yep. The problem occurs if I just change some random line in the body of the deleted foo() function. I've double-checked the basic steps with my collegue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not a SVN expert, but I can suggest you is to export a patch from a commit of your first branch and to apply the patch into the second branch.

I guess this is almost what the Mercurial 'hg transplant XXX' command does. I don't know if any SVN equivalent command exists, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you change a function on the trunk that you have deleted on the branch, you can expect a conflict, this is natural.

And yes, for the "right-hand-side", you will see all the changes between the trunk and branch.  If you think about it, this is the only set of changes that it is logical to show.  (At least, that is the case with version 1.4 on the server; later versions with better merge tracking may possibly be able to be more concise, but you would need to have a sufficient client version, I'm not sure.  I really need to upgrade ... sigh.)  But the branch changes shown should all be automatically marked as unmodified by the merge, unless they conflict or otherwise interact with changes from the trunk.

You should never be surprised by the set of changes you see.  If you are, then you have either selected the wrong revisions or you are misunderstanding something about how the merge process works.